# control over what prints on first and second page of pdf

Tags: 6, files

I am generating pdf using dompdf and my website is running on Drupal 6.
I have a requirement wherein I need to print part of my html on first page and some part on second page in some cases. 
Also some part remains same for both the pages like header and footer, etc.
How do I acheive that? Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to achieve that with dompdf. It's impossible to control the page flow when producing PDF files based on HTML pages.

I found an interesting module that has a completely different approach: [Views PDF](http://drupal.org/project/views_pdf). It also has an administrative interface to compose your document.

Unfortunatly I did not test it myself yet, but it's scheduled for a new project in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Yea...I am using TCPDF now. I have acheived what i wanted by tweating my HTML. Thanks for your time, will definately check out Views PDF. :)